# Why is my image not being passed to my ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have my app set up so that there will be multiple image pickers, each with it's own array of images.  The user will press which set they wish to view, select an image, and then the app will pop back to the Root Controller.  I want the image they have selected to be added as a SubView to my main ViewController.

I'm having issues getting the main ViewController to detect the image selected though.

Here's how I am trying:

In my Image Picker:

**EDIT** I'm having an issue again.  I have added a new viewController so the users will choose which set of array of images they want to see instead of going straight to the array of images.  I changed the way I pop to the viewController since I am not going back to the RootViewController now.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    _selectedImage = [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.viewController.stampedImage = _selectedImage;
    NSLog(@"delegate.viewController = %@", delegate.viewController);
    NSLog(@"delegate.viewController.stampedImage = %@", delegate.viewController.stampedImage);
    NSLog(@"_selectedImage = %@", _selectedImage);
    [delegate.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
}
```

I've ran an NSLog here and the selectedImage is set to an image.

Here is what I am doing in my main ViewController where I want the image to appear.  I am running this code in viewWillAppear:

```
//stampedImage = _imagePicker.selectedImage;  --- Not sure if I need this line
_stampedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:stampedImage];
NSLog(@"ViewController stampedImage = %@", stampedImage);
[_stampedImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80.0, 80.0)];
[_stampedImageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[_stampedImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageView addSubview:_stampedImageView];
[_stampedImageView release];
```

I've ran an NSLog here but the stampedImage always returns as null. 
**The stampedImage is always coming back as null**

I have the stampedImage set as a property and is being synthesized.
I have also set done an @class in the .h for my image picker class.

Any ideas?  I'm stumped on this one for some reason.

Comment: Saying you have ran an `NSLog` "here" is very unhelpful.  Please edit your code to show exactly where you are doing it.

Comment: I have also noticed that if I pushViewController the new image does get added but the one I took with the camera is gone.  If I popToViewController the camera image is there but the selected image is not being added.